# MediaWiki Restrict Editing on Pages

Tags: mediawiki

I am currently trying to set up a MediaWiki Site, but I don't want anyone to edit the pages.

I want to set it up so that only certain users can edit certain pages, does anyone know of any way that this can be achieved? I have had a look at the extensions but so far I am drawing a blank.

Anyone know of anything that I can use?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it anything on your choice cause MediaWiki treats editing a **Talk page** the same as editing any other page in the wiki but check out  https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TalkRight.

**It does what you want.**

Comment: Thank you, I shall take a look at that later!

Comment: If you find it helpful...plz accept the answer..@Bob

Comment: actually original question is about restricting edit action to certain pages. Not sure this is possible. May be there is some extension.

Comment: Shobhit, I need to test it first.

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ArticleProtection, does the job I want.